# I receive ModuleNotFoundError only when the package is downloaded from PyPI

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

I am working on a Back Up system named **RunUp** - Is still on a very early stage.

You can see all the source code on its [GitHub page](https://github.com/kennylajara/runup). And also, I uploaded it to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/RunUp/), so, probably you won't have any problem to see what is happening by your self.

Well, this is the thing:

If you download the repo, move to the root, create your virtual environment and run `pip install --editable .` (do not omit the dot), you will see that the installation runs well and if you use `runup --version` it will show the output `RunUp, version 0.1.dev4`. Everything is OK.

But...

If you open a new console (or uninstall the package) and download it directly from PyPI with `pip install runup`, it will be installed without problem but when you use it (running again `runup --version`) it will output an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/path/to/repo/venv/bin/runup", line 5, in <module>
    from src.runup.cli import cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I don't know very well why this is happening but I may think that is related to my [setuptools implementation](https://github.com/kennylajara/runup/blob/main/setup.py) or the directory tree. Not really sure about that.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of your `site-packages`?

Comment: Remove the `src.`. It's only a folder in the repo. -->`from runup.cli import cli`

Comment: @SvenEberth If I do that I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'runup'
`

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Yes, I have `RunUp.egg-link` there.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Reinstalled as I was looking at the wrong venv and the file that I have in the `sites-package` is `RunUp-0.1.dev4.dist-info`

Comment: tbh I'm not very familiar with the writing of setup.py, but I think you forgot the `packages` or `package_dir` argument. The [download files](https://pypi.org/project/RunUp/#files) at PyPi doesn't contain anything from the src-folder.

Comment: @SvenEberth Thanks, Solved. I had to include `packages=setuptools.find_packages(),`